# Is it possible to build Android and iOS apps in TFS2017?

Tags: android, ios, tfs

I believe the new version of TFS won't offer native support for Android and iOS (unless the code is in C++), but in what ways could that be worked around?

Let's say I have a mobile client that has a version for every platform - Android, Windows Phone, iOS. The way I make a new build for Windows Phone is: open Visual Studio, find the right build definition and queue a new build, and then the build commences on a build agent and the output is copied to the folder that's specified in the build definition.

Is it possible to have that procedure for the iOS and Android apps as well? Currently, the procedure is using a Hudson build server, but I'd like to have build definitions for iOS and Android and just queue new builds through Visual Studio and receive the output .ipa and .apk files in the folder specified in the definition.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

On-premise TFS supports cross-platform build since TFS 2015, in the new tasks based build system. Check [Continuous integration on any platform](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/overview).

To build an Android app, use Gradle task: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/build/gradle

To build Xcode project, use Xcode build task: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/mobile/xcode-ios

In addition, TFS 2017 has some default build definition you can use directly: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/build